# Error when apply default value in migration Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('render', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('displayed')->default(false);
    });
}
```

When I try to run this migration using:
`php artisan migrate`

I receive the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]        
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Fluent::default()
```

How can I be resolving?

I've tried to update the `composer`, I've tried changing the column name, I've done several things, however, only this specific migration presents the problem.

Class Link: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Fluent.php

Laravel Documentation 5.2:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: I guess you're not using Laravel 5.2

Comment: I looked at the composer.json file to confirm, and indeed I'm on 5.2.
I also realized that in 5.0 there was no such thing as `default`, only in 5.1 onwards.

Comment: `composer self-update 1.10.17;` try to downgrade your composer version, or make sure that you have imported the correct namespace for the `Schema` and `Blueprint`